# Unity game is having lags after integrating admob ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I just finished developing my 2d sidescroller game and after I integrated admob I am having occassional lags (the game play is not smooth as before). I called the admob sdk load function both in start() and update(). I dont know why its happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device an older and slower phone or tablet? If it is then the loading of the ads stresses the CPU which, of course, causes FPS hiccups to your game.

Comment: I tried it on bluestacks.I dont have an android device with me now. Is there any possible way to do it on a different thread?? I think it sometimes misses the key inputs on some frames as the ad tries to load

Comment: I now tried it on android device aswell. It still have the lag. Is there any workaround????